# I am receiving a 400 error due to an unexpected URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to get data using Ajax. My backend-framework is [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter), and the `get_data` function call error occurs:

```
http://localhost/qasim/outlets/[object%20Object] 400 (Bad Request)
```

The main problem is this: After outlets, there is some garbage which is not present in the actual URL.

How do I fix this problem?

```
function get_data(l)
{
    myurl="http://localhost/qasim/outlets/home_controller/get_pros";

    $.post({
        url:myurl,
        data:{last:l},
        dataType:'json',

    }
    ,function (data){alert("success");});
}


$(function (){
    $(window).scroll(function (e){
        get_data(4);
        console.log(window.pageYOffset);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You aren't using [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) correctly. It doesn't take an object as the first argument.

The correct usage is:

```
$.post(myurl, {last:l}, function (data){
    alert("success");
}, 'json');
```

The method signature for `$.post` is:

> jQuery.post( URL [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is little incorrect, due to "data:{last:1}", because the second argument is an object or String.

Correct is:

```
$.post(
    myurl, 
    {last:l},
    function (data){alert("success");},
    'json'
 );
```

PS: I see that the first answer is corrected. All is OK )